# Exterior covariant derivative for a bundle-valued $n$-form for a connection without torsion

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, connections

Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle above a manifold $M$, with a connection $\nabla$ defined on the tangent bundle, and let $\nabla^{E}$ be a linear connection on $E$ and $\omega$ a $n$-form on $M$ with valued in $E$ i.e. an element of $\Omega^n(M, E)$.

From different sources, I gather the following definitions and a result (using usual notations)

1. The exterior covariant derivative of $\omega$ is an element of $\Omega^{n+1}(M, E)$ defined by
   $$d^{E}\omega(X_{0}, \dots, X_{n})=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^{i}\nabla_{X_{i}}^{E}(\omega(X_{0}, \dots,\hat{X}_{i}, \dots, X_{n}))\\
   +\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j}\omega([X_{i},X_{j}], X_{0}, \dots, \hat{X}_{i}, \dots, \hat{X}_{j}, \dots, X_{n})$$
2. The covariant derivative of $\omega$ is an element of $\Omega^1(M)\otimes\Omega^n(M, E)$, and not of $\Omega^{n+1}(M, E)$, defined by
   $$(\nabla_{X}^{E}\omega)(X_{1},\dots, X_n)=\nabla_X^{E}.(\omega((X_{1},\dots, X_n))
   -\sum_{i=1}^n \omega(X_{1},\dots, \nabla_{X}X_{i},\dots, X_n)$$
3. When the connection on $M$ is symmetric, i.e. without torsion, then the two are connected by
   $$d^{E}\omega(X_{0}, \dots, X_{n})=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i}\nabla_{X_i}^{E}\omega(X_0, \dots, \hat{X}_i \dots, X_n)$$

The proof of 3 seems easy enough by unravelling the definitions, but I was unable to find clear references that do not use local coordinates for definition 2 and formula 3 proof. Do they make sense and where can I find them?

Comment: As for 2., what is your definition of the covariant derivative of $\omega$? Because, as far as I'm concerned, that formula would be the definition. Though it should be $X(\omega(X_1,\dotsc,X_n))$.

Comment: @thorgott it cannot be what you suggest because $\ omega(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ belongs to E. But yes it is definition 2.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry, I was thinking still of the $E=TM$ case. Anyway, so the question only is how to prove formula 3?

Comment: @thorgott not even about the proof which is easy. I am just looking at some references about these definitions & result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually by digging around more deeply I found this quite interesting and detailed answer of Ribeiro to an MO question
[Ribeiro_answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/347037/3333)
that generalizes this result to higher order iteration of the derivatives and the connections, with or without torsion.